# PHP Library to get command line options and parameters

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-arguments

Is there a PHP library that I can use to parse options *and* parameters in a command line php script? I do know the function `getopt`, but is there something similar for parameters?

Comment: There is a Symfony2 component that wraps command-line usage up nicely if you're in to that sort of thing: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getopt` for options and the `$argv` array for parameters - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

also have a look at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php for stuff like reading arguments from `$argv` of the form `--name=VALUE`

Answer (score 8):

`getopt` is a possibility but it's no fun, especially not if you're used to Python (or Ruby, which probably has similarly beautiful argv parsers). Here are some better alternatives, they probably all require PHP 5.3+.

- I've tried [Commando](https://github.com/nategood/commando) and I'm happy with it.
- [ConsoleKit](https://github.com/maximebf/ConsoleKit) would have been next in line.
- [php-cli-tools](https://github.com/jlogsdon/php-cli-tools) has some more functionality such as progress indicators and tabular displays. I only found it 10 minutes ago, since I want tabular display I might move to this library from Commando at some point.
- Also check [GetOptionKit](https://github.com/c9s/php-GetOptionKit) as it can handle subcommands.

Comment: Commando seems alright. Doesn't play nicely with my IDE due to the magic `__call` methods, but it works well and it's easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [CLIFramework](https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework) it handles subcommands, argument validation, option values (multiple, flag, optional, default) and a powerful zsh/bash completion generator.

Here is a screencast of using zsh completion generator (it completes arguments and options):

[image: zsh completion generator]

There are also many popular applications using CLIFramework and GetOptionKit. e.g., [PHPBrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew), [LazyRecord](https://github.com/c9s/LazyRecord)

Answer (score 0):

You can use robust and well developed libraries

- [symfony/console](https://github.com/symfony/console) - more complicated but powerfull
- [wp-cli/php-cli-tools](https://github.com/wp-cli/php-cli-tools) - easy to use, much smaller